# What is the maximum idle time for a node to be considered active?

Tags: nodes

Maybe I'm wrong but I remember I read somewhere that a node will be considered active for a certain period even if it is not responding for a certain time (something in the order of minutes).

Does anyone know if this is true?

If this is the case, how long is the maximum idle time for a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no traffic on a connection, nodes will periodically send a message to maintain the connection. If a node has not communicated on a connection for more than 90 minutes, it is assumed to be disconnected and a new peer will be found.
A more detailed explanation is given in the book [**Mastering Bitcoin** by O'Reilly Chimera](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802). The specific explanation is given [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch06.html#_network_discovery)